# Bloc changes state when the response is different but the status Code is 200. ( flutter )

Tags: flutter, api, error-handling, bloc, clean-architecture

I have bloc which I used to login, The problem is if the phone I'm entering  is related to a deleted account the bloc changes state to ErrorState.

if the phone is correct the json looks like this

```
{
"status": true,
"msg": "Done",
"data": {
    "name": "",
    "phone": "",
    "email": "",
    "status": "",
    "address": "",
    "address_short": "",
    "address_link": "",
    "api_token":  "",
    "otp": 2379
}}
```

If the account is deleted this is the json response

```
{
"status": false,
"msg": "deleted account"
}
```

bloc snippet

```
AuthBloc({required this.auth, required this.sendOTP}) : super(AuthInitial()) {
on<AuthEvent>((event, emit) async {
  if (event is LoginOrRegisterEvent) {
    emit(LoadingState());

    final loginOrRegister = await auth.call(
      phone: event.phone,
      name: event.phone,
    );
    loginOrRegister.fold(
      (failure) {
        emit(ErrorAuthState(message: AppFunctions.mapFailureToMessage(failure: failure)));
      },
      (auth) {
        emit(LoadedAuthState(authEntity: auth));
      },
    );
  }
}); }
```

I'm using clean architecture here is my remote data source code

```
    class AuthRemoteDataSourceImpl implements AuthRemoteDataSource {
  @override
  Future<AuthModel> auth({
    required String phone,
    required String name,
    String? fcmToken,
  }) async {
    final response = await DioHelper.postData(
      url: ApiConstants.login,
      data: {
        'phone': phone,
        'name': name,
        'fcmToken': fcmToken ?? '',
      },
      headers: {},
    );

    if (response!.statusCode == 200) {
      final authModel = AuthModel.fromJson(response.data);
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print('--------------- user Token --------------------');
        print(authModel.token);
        print('------------------------------------------------');
      }

      return authModel;
    } else {
      throw ServerException();
    }
  }}
```

here is my Auth Repository

```
class AuthRepositoryImpl implements AuthRepository {
  final AuthRemoteDataSource authRemoteDataSource;
  final NetworkInfo networkInfo;

  AuthRepositoryImpl({required this.authRemoteDataSource, required this.networkInfo});

  @override
  Future<Either<Failure, AuthEntity>> auth({
    required String phone,
    required String name,
    String? fcmToken,
  }) async {
    if (await networkInfo.isConnected) {
      try {
        final remoteProfile = await authRemoteDataSource.auth(
          phone: phone,
          name: name,
          fcmToken: fcmToken ?? '',
        );
        return Right(remoteProfile);
      } on ServerException {
        return Left(ServerFailure());
      } catch (error) {
        return Left(ServerFailure());
      }
    } else {
      return Left(NoInternetConnectionFailure());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to debug it step by step and check from where it is breaking

Comment: can you provide `AuthModel` code?